# opencv 3.4.1 visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, visual-c++

i'm runing a simple code

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include"iostream"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    Mat image1 = imread("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Tulips.jpg");
    Mat image = imread("Koala.jpg");
    if (image.empty())
    {
        cout << "no image" << endl;
        system("pause");

    }
    imshow("win1", image1);
    waitKey(0);

    imshow("win2", image);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

when i run the code using "start without debugging (ctrl+f5)" it runs fine and the ouput image appear.
but when i run it using "start debugging (f5)" it gives opencv_world341d.dll is missing.
how to fix this.

Comment: In properties(in Debug mode) in Linker->input -> in additional dependencies have you added opencv_world341d.lib

Comment: @TaheraTabassum yes i have and the code runs fine without debugging i don't know why whent start debugging it's not

Comment: if its working fine in 'release mode/ without debugging mode' and throwing error in 'with debugging mode' then there must be some properties that you have set in debugging that are not correct which is making it throw this error.

Answer (score 0):

This happen because the application couldn't find the correct dll, there are 2 solutions for this problem.

1. Add dll to exe location
2. Add dll to system path

The "opencv_world341d.dll" can be found in this location **$OPENCV_INSTALL_DIR/build/x64/vc15/bin**

hope this helps...